# How to open mxml file from other mxml file?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

In my flex 3 application, i am maintaining two `mxml` files say `one.mxml` and `two.mxml`. How can i call `two.mxml` from `one.mxml`. I don't want to use any variables from different `mxml` files. I want to redirect it. How it can be? Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no concept of calling or redirection in MXML, it's a markup language. You can define controls in mxml files and use one in another, if that's what you want.

Comment: Hei.. flex is not html!!! :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var pop:mxmlFileName= mxmlFileName(PopUpManager.createPopUp(Sprite(Application.application),mxmlFileName,true));
PopUpManager.centerPopUp(pop);
```

I stumbled upon this while debugging a project I am working on. Not sure if it is optimised anyway but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply create an instance, then add it to stage:
    `var one:One=new One();
    addElement(one);`
but don't forget, one.mxml must not be an application, only a component. if it is so, you have to reedit the main node of the mxml.